# Right css code to align(center) the div tag?

Tags: css

I googled this question and searched for an hour, every one specify their own likes, but i want to know the correct code to align the div in center position.

Comment: This question is better suited (and answered several times) on stackoverflow.com -> http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=center+div

Comment: As your research has shown, everyone has their own 'likes'--there is no one 'correct' way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok if you give your div an id of #centerdiv, the following css should center it

```
#centerdiv {  margin: 0 auto; }
```

be aware that you will have to give that div a width value as well

Comment: also this article may be of use here -http://designshack.net/articles/css/how-to-center-anything-with-css/